# adb devices command doesn't show my xperia z - got proper drivers and all

Tags: android, adb, sony-xperia, fastboot

I am trying to flash a custom rom and therefore I need to run certain adb commands. Now the thing is the when I'm booted in to fastboot everything is okay, the

```
fastboot devices
```

command recognizes my phone(C6603). Also the device is shown as an Android device - sony fastboot interface in the device manager. But if I try to run

```
adb devices
```

command no device is found..

I'm kind of hopeless here is/are some additional info/things I've tried:

- I flashed throughout Kingo root and I'm on firmware .74
- USB debugging is, of course, on
- I tried both media transfer and mass storage
- I tried different usb ports and rebooting adb several times
- I tried adding the device id to adb_usb.ini. Though I'm not sure about my device id
- I installed the drivers with for the 'fastboot device' with Flashtool and also installed fasbtboot and ADT drivers.
- I'm on Windows 8(x64)

I hope someone can help me out. Otherwise I should consider ADB Wireless as my last option

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not belong to SO, but rather to devices/SU/...

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone else is still looking for a solution, this worked for me:

Download the device drivers from here http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/

Open the device manager, check whether your device name (e.g. C6903) is listed under "Other devices". If so, right click on it and select "update drivers", and use the ones you just downloaded. Done!

The problem is that the device connects as two separate devices when usb debugging is enabled on the phone, and windows didn't recognize the "debugging device". So I had to install the appropriate drivers manually.

Comment: Thanks for that hint! I'm going to add that this check should be done in fastboot mode. Alternatively, you can try the ones at http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2635830

Answer (score 1):

I figured that I need to use `adb reboot-boatloader` to boot TO fastboot and not use any adb commands while in fastboot. This was basically what cost me over 4 hours. Hope it helps anyone.