# adb can't detect my sony xperia z5 compact

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, sony-xperia, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I'm trying to unlock the bootloader on my Sony Xperia z5 compact but when I have to plug the device on the computer, nothing appear to be attached:

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
```

I'm under Osx Mavericks. I also tryied on Windows 7 (sp1) without success.
I enabled developer mode and OEM unlocking.

I found there [adb can't detect Sony Xperia s although I installed driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107545/adb-cant-detect-sony-xperia-s-although-i-installed-driver) that I must put my phone in Mass Storage mode, but there isn't this option in the menu, I only have:

- Charge only
- MTP (MEdia Transfer Protocol)
- PTP (Picture Transfer Protocol)
- RNDIS (USB Ethernet)
- Audio Source
- MIDI

Also, when I choose one option from this menu it doesn't seem to save it as if I close and reopen the options it resets it.

I tryied this solution <[adb devices command doesn't show my xperia z - got proper drivers and all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044582/adb-devices-command-doesnt-show-my-xperia-z-got-proper-drivers-and-all)> on Windows without success.

I'm on Marshmallow 6.0.1. The phone model number is E5823.

Do you have any tips? Suggestions?
At this point I'm really desperate...

Comment: When I do: `adb reboot-bootloader` I have this message: `error: no devices/emulators found`

Comment: If you don't have the connection. It's bricked.
Do you see it's soft or hard bricked ?

Comment: No I must have expressed myself badly... The first procedure to root the phone is to unlock the bootloader, it's what i'm trying to do. To unlock that I need to connect the device to the computer and then enter a command that Sony provides (`fastboot.exe -i 0x0fce oem unlock 0xKEY`. Repalce KEY with the code provided by Sony). My problem is that when I plug in my phone keeping volume up pressed I can see the blue light on the phone but the device isn't detected by the pc... (ref: http://techbeasts.com/how-to-unlock-bootloader-of-sony-xperia-devices-guide/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off the phone while connecting it to the computer, press and hold the Volume Up key. The notification LED becomes Blue.

Install fastboot drivers. To do this, follow a tutorial with the method of your choice, and using the Unlock_SE xperia_bootloaders.zip file.